# can't create .csv file by python in php script

Tags: php, python, csv

I have python code and i am running it from the php script.

PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) /* i.e. the PHP code is executed only when someone presses Submit button in the below given HTML Form */
{
$var = $_POST['any_name'];   // Here $var is the input taken from user.
}

$last=exec('/home/ankit/anaconda/bin/python data_pull.py --q kunal',$output,$return);
echo $last;
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="any_name">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Python code:

```
 from apiclient.discovery import build      #pip install google-api-python-client
from apiclient.errors import HttpError      #pip install google-api-python-client
from oauth2client.tools import argparser    #pip install oauth2client
import pandas as pd                 #pip install pandas
import csv
import sys 

DEVELOPER_KEY = "key here" 
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"


#ALS Ice Bucket Challenge

argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default = 'bollywood')
                #change the default to the search term you want to search
argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=40)
                #default number of results which are returned. It can vary from 0 - 100
args = argparser.parse_args()
options = args

youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

# Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
 # query term.
search_response = youtube.search().list(
 q=options.q,
 type="video",
 part="id,snippet",
 maxResults=options.max_results
).execute()

videos = {}

# Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
 # matching videos.
 # Filter out channels, and playlists.
for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
 if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
 #videos.append("%s" % (search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
    videos[search_result["id"]["videoId"]] = search_result["snippet"]["title"]

#print "Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n"

s = ','.join(videos.keys())


videos_list_response = youtube.videos().list(
 id=s,
 part='id,statistics,snippet'
).execute()


res = []
for i in videos_list_response['items']:
 temp_res = dict(v_id = i['id'], v_title = videos[i['id']])
 temp_res.update(i['statistics'])
 temp_res.update(i['snippet'])
 res.append(temp_res)

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res)
print 'ankit is here3'
#print res

f=open('youtube.csv', 'w')
w=csv.writer(f)
print 'ankit is here3'
"""
for r in res:
#with open('youtube.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,r.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(res)

row=[]
for key, value in res[0].iteritems() :
    row.append(key)
w.writerow(row)
print row

"""
#print res

print 'ankit is here3'
for r in res:
    row=[]
    small_row=''
    if 'commentCount' in r.keys():
        item=r['commentCount'].encode("ascii")
        row.append(item)
    else:
        row.append('0')
    item=r['viewCount'].encode("ascii") 
    #row.append(r['viewCount'].encode("ascii"))
    row.append(item)
    #row.append(r['v_title'].encode("ascii"))
    item=r['v_title'].encode('ascii','ignore')
    row.append(item)
    #row.append(r['dislikeCount'].encode("ascii"))  
    if 'dislikeCount' in r.keys():
        item=r['dislikeCount'].encode("ascii")
        row.append(item)
    else:
        row.append('0') 
    #item=r['dislikeCount'].encode("ascii")
    #row.append(item)
    #row.append(r['v_id'].encode("ascii"))
    item=r['v_id'].encode("ascii")
    row.append(item)
    #row.append(r['favoriteCount'].encode("ascii"))
    item=r['favoriteCount'].encode("ascii") 
    row.append(item)
    #row.append(r['likeCount'].encode("ascii"))
    #item=r['likeCount'].encode("ascii")    
    #row.append(item)
    if 'likeCount' in r.keys():
        item=r['likeCount'].encode("ascii")
        row.append(item)
    else:
        row.append('0')
    if 'tags' in r.keys():      
        for t in r['tags']:
            t=t.encode("ascii",'ignore')
            small_row = small_row + '/' + t 
        row.append(small_row)
    else:
        row.append('0')
    #row.append(r['channelId'])
    #row.append(r['categoryId'])
    #row.append(r['thumbnails'])
    w.writerow(row)
    print row
```

Actually i am writing a csv file in code for further use. The code is working fine without being in php, but it's not creating any file while running in php in folder `/var/www/html/`.

The output while running in php is:

```
ankit is here3
```

I am not getting the error.

Comment: please fix your python code's indentation

Comment: does the user that runs `apache` have write access to the folder `/var/www/html`?

Comment: I tried exec('whoami')  Result = www-data     Then i gave all permissions to folder by                        ' sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/'. Then also not working...?

Comment: did you try:   python /home/ankit/anaconda/bin/python data_pull.py --q kunal          adding python before the command might help. just a guess. or maybe try shell_exec instead of exec. also you need to chmod /home/ankit/anaconda/bin/python instead of /var/www/html

Comment: Again same thing happening I tried both things Shell_exec() and gave permissions to /home/ankit/anaconda/bin/python.

Comment: do you get `/var/www/html` if you put `os.system('pwd')` or `print os.getcwd()` in your python script?

Comment: @Omar Yeah got the output like `/var/www/html 0 ankit is here3` after adding `print os.system('pwd')`

Comment: if you type `print os.access('.', os.W_OK)` in your python script, does it print True?, if so, is there a chance that you already have a `youtube.csv` file in the `/var/www/html` folder?, if you have a 'youtube.csv' file, it may be owned by a different user so `www-data` will no be able to modify it, and you will have to delete it first

Comment: @Omar It returned 'True'  but there is no file youtube.csv in folder `/var/www/html/`

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, maybe surround your code with a try catch to see what's the exception `try: 
  #your_code 
except: 
  print sys.exc_info()[1]`